# Backpack v3 table grid suddenly is not loading in localhost

Tags: laravel-backpack

Backpack v3 Table grid suddenly is not loading in localhost. Very rarely it loads after a long time.
It is fine on the online website.
Has anyone experienced this issue. Could it be because of some browser update?

Comment: If a red error bubble pops up, check your Chrome Dev Tools for the error. That should provide some more insight.

Comment: The error I see in Chrome Dev Tools is - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Comment: Sorry, never got anything like that, in 4+ years of using Backpack every day. I recommend you google the error and work from that. Can't be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and solution given here

[PHP7.0-fpm extremly slow on Ubuntu Windows Subsystem Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286420/php7-0-fpm-extremly-slow-on-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-linux)

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2100