# nginx on WSL2 takes minutes to load the page after few requests

Tags: nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I did read and try the following;

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286973/8068675 *listen = 127.0.0.1:9000;*
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615652/8068675 *disable buffering*
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/393#issuecomment-442498519 *disable buffering + different config*

But none of theses fixed the issue.

**Issue**
From Windows; when I browse my website located in WSL2 through `http://myproject.test`, `https://myproject.test` or `127.0.0.1` the first 2-3 requests are going fast (<100 ms). Then the next requests takes exactly 60000ms (1 minute) to be received when they are not blocked.

**Configuration on Windows 10**

- Firewall disabled
- `127.0.0.1 myproject.test` added to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- [mkcerts](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) installed
- WSL 2 installed with Ubuntu 20.04 on it

**Configuration on WSL 2**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- nginx 1.18
- mysql 8.0
- php-fpm 7.4

**Project**

- Laravel
- location `/home/clement/projects/myproject/`
- certs (generated with mkcert) `/home/clement/projects/certs/`
- owner: `clement:www-data`
- permission : `777` (It's only for test and development purpose)

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject.test**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /home/clement/projects/certs/myproject.test.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/clement/projects/certs/myproject.test-key.pem;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;

    server_name myproject.test;
    root /home/clement/projects/myproject/public;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffering off;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

I have the same issue using `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` or `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;`

When I do `php -S localhost:8080` or `php artisan serve` in the project, everything's working fine.

**Edit with log**
This is the log I'm getting on nginx, but even with this information I still cannot find any resource that fix the issue.

> 2020/08/07 23:06:30 [error] 1987#1987: *6 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myproject.test, request: "GET /_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1588748787 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "myproject.test", referrer: "http://myproject.test/"

Or using IP

> 2020/08/08 01:43:01 [error] 4080#4080: *4 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myproject.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "myproject.test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the issue. Despite I followed the instruction to install WSL 2, it was using WSL 1.

In **powershell** I ran
`wsl -l -v` and got the result

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         NAME        |       STATE      |      VERSION     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    Ubuntu-20.04     |      Stopped     |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

After [updating the kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel) I could change the version to 2 with the command
`wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2`

and now everything works well